# Show that if $G$ is a connected graph of order $n≥2$ and $k$ is an integer with $1≤k≤n-1$, then $G^k$ is $k$-connected.

Tags: graph-theory

Show that if $G$ is a connected graph of order $n≥2$ and $k$ is an integer with $1≤k≤n-1$, then $G^k$ is $k$-connected.

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track, but I tried to prove this by induction

Base: $n=2$ then $k=1$ and we have  $G^1=P_2$ clearly  $1$-connected

Inductive: Assume this is true for $n=l$ then $G^k$ is $k$-connected with $1\le k\le l-1$, I'm not sure this give me any useful information to to show this is true for $n=l+1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use induction.

Suppose $S$ is a vertex cut in $G^k$ with less than $k$ vertices and $v$ and $w$ are two vertices separated by $S$.

If $d_G(v,w)\leq k$, then $v$ and $w$ are neighbours in $G^k$, so they cannot be separated by $S$.

Otherwise the shortest path $P$ (in $G$) has more then $k$ internal vertices.
In order to avoid that $P-S$ still contains a path from $v$ to $w$ (in $G^k$) $S$ must take away at least $k$
consecutive vertices and this is impossible.

Therefore $G^k$ must be $k$-connected.

Comment: $u$ and $w$ are two vertices separated by $x$ meaning $x$ is a vertex adjacent to both $u$ and $w$ or $x$ lie on $y-W$ path?

Comment: S is a vertex cut in $G^k$. $x$ and $y$ are separated by $S$ if they are in different components of $G^k-S$. There was a typo in the answer, which is fixed now.

Comment: so by saying $x,y$ you mean $v,w$?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I decided to change variable names halfway the proof. A bad idea, apparently.